# C# Error getting row from data table when it contains mixed characters - any advice or an alternative route appreciated

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I get an excel sheet into a data table as follows

```
string excelAddressListPath = basePath + "/PROPERTIES.xlsx";
if (!File.Exists(excelAddressListPath))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Missing dependency address file DB, exiting....");
    System.Environment.Exit(-1);
}

DataTable dt;

System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
using (var stream = File.Open(excelAddressListPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream)) 
    {
        var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
        {
            ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
            {
                UseHeaderRow = true
            }
        };

        var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);
        dt = dataSet.Tables[0];  
    }  
}
```

I then have the retrieve data in a function

```
string GetAddressFromDataTable(DataTable dt, string uprn)
{
    string address = "";

    Console.WriteLine(uprn);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Select($"[Property Reference] = '{uprn}'"))
    {
        address = row["Property Address"].ToString();
    }

    return address;

}
```

Which i call as follows

```
string address = GetAddressFromDataTable(dt, uprn.ToUpper());
Console.WriteLine($"From DB: {address}");
```

All works well when the property reference is a number 12345 but fails if it has characters such as B12345

Ive tried various ways but as i think everything is already a string i cant understand my error

error below

```
Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Double and System.String.
```

Comment: Can't help but think you're painting yourself into a corner with this one, using an excel reader lib that seems no longer maintained (last release 5 years ago?) and data storage containers that were on the way out last decade (datatable). Perhaps start over with a modern library and read your excel files to a collection of objects that you can more easily query with LINQ

Comment: Personally I tend to use Sylvan these days - https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan.Data.Excel - and, folllowing the example in the readme there, something like `var items = edr.GetRecords<Property>(); var b12345Property = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.PropertyReference == "B12345");`

Comment: @flackoverstow thank you i will check this out, this is my first venture into C# in quite a while. I have had to find a library that allows commercial use although it is a non profit organisation I want to keep things free and above board with licensing.

Comment: If you can adjust the question to include a "if there is an alternative way to achieve this" then I could propose an answer with the library I've recommended, but at the moment the way it's posed I cannot give a walkthrough for an alternative. The library you have used to read the excel file to a datatable has determined that the property reference column is numeric and has made a numeric column in the datatable. When using Select with it (which is nothing to do with modern LINQ Select by the way) the expression selected is trying to convert the string 'B12345' to a number to match the column

Comment: Thanks, I have and I'm new to C#, I have working program in python but my employer needs it in C#, its not been too hard to get this far and I'm nearly done just a few issues to iron out.

Comment: Try `dt.Select($"Convert([Property Reference], 'System.String') = '{uprn}'")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't use DataTables so much these days; the modern route would perhaps be to find a library that will bind an excel file to a list of objects, and make a strongly typed class to represent our file data then work with that

I'll show you an example using the Sylvan.Data.Excel library - this is actively developed and the author is reachable here and on github where the library is hosted. This can often be a deciding factor in favour of using a library, as bugs can be rectified and the best support is available from an active author.

We use Nuget Package Manager to add Sylvan.Data and Sylvan.Data.Excel to our app:

[image]

We have an Excel file that w want to read. Let's also assume we don't have any interest in the Year Built column:

[image]

We have a class to represent a house, called Property (not a great name given that a property in C# is something else, but it'll work. Just remember that when I say prop or property with a lower case `p` I'm referring to a C# property like `int Blah {get;set;}`, not a house):

```
class Property
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "Property Reference")]
        public string PropertyReference { get; set; } = "";

        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        [DataMember(Name = "Purchase Date")]
        public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "SQFT")]
        public int SquareFeet { get; set; }

        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public bool Active { get; set; }

    }
```

You can see that the class has properties like `public int SquareFeet` whose names don't match the columns of the file. We use the `DataMember` attribute to specify which column in the file maps to this prop. Where the name aligns (e.g. "Name") we can skip this

We have a prop that we are going to use for some internal purpose and won't be read from or written to a file. We annotate this with `IgnoreDataMember` otherwise Sylvan will complain it couldn't find it in the file

We also have a column we aren't interested in, and there is no property for this, so it won't be read

---

Now we can read the excel file in and query it:

```
using Sylvan.Data;
using Sylvan.Data.Excel;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static async Task Main()
        {

            using var edr = ExcelDataReader.Create("c:\\temp\\property.xlsx");

            var properties = edr.GetRecords<Property>().ToArray();

            var b12345 = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyReference == "B12345");

            if (b12345 != default)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Name of prop with ref B12345 is {b12345.Name}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Prop with ref B12345 is not found");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The first line of Main establishes a reader to the file (don't have  it open in Excel)

The second does the read of all 3 properties into an array

The third runs a query using LINQ, for the first property with a ref of B12345. If you're new to C# you may not have seen this, so here's a quick breakdown:

```
p => p.PropertyReference == "B12345"
```

This is what we call a lambda, or a delegate. It's like a method, code that takes arguments and does something, but it has no name - it doesn't need one because it's only used in one place

`FirstOrDefault` is a method that is specified to run on a collection of objects. Its only argument is that you, the programmer, shall pass to it is a tiny method that takes an argument of the type of object in the colelction, and returns a boolean. FirstOrDefault will loop over your collection, calling your lambda once for each element in the collection, and passing in the current element. If your lambda returns true, that is the element that FirstOrDefault will return

This lambda thus will result in FirstOrDefault inspecting the reference for each object and returning the proeprty with reference B12345; `p` is the currenty Property in the array, and FirstOrDefault goes sequentially from start to finish, as if like this pseudocode:

```
Property FirstOrDefault(properties, lambdaThatTakesAPropertyAndReturnsABool){

    foreach(var property in properties){
        if(lambdaThatTakesAPropertyAndReturnsABool(property) == true)
            return property;
    }
    return null; //didn't find
}
```

LINQ is a huge topic, out of scope for here. You can make a reasonable start from the docs but they're very confusing to read. Better to find a nice tutorial

Comment: 'We don't use DataTables so much these days'. True, but one case where I for one regularly use them is exactly in reading from xlsx files. This is because I almost invariably am doing this to insert into a SQL Server database, and SqlBulkCopy requires DataTable, DataRow[] or a DataReader as source.  I ended up writing my own library to read (and write) xlsx (it's not that difficult provided you're dealing with relatively plain data files).

Comment: Fair comment; nothing about the OP's question indicated a bulk copy was in progress, but perhaps one good thing about Sylvan in this regard is that it implements a DbDataReader so you should be able to bulk copy directly from an excel file without the interim memory storage of the DataTable. Mark specifically tries to keep memory allocation for Sylvan lowest in class, so I'd assume it's possible to end up with a very quick and efficient solution using it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your column "[Property Reference]" is declared by a number. Check on the file the data type of this column.

This code is strange because you will return only the last string.

```
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Select($"[Property Reference] = '{uprn}'"))
    {
        address = row["Property Address"].ToString();
    }

    return address;
```

Comment: So maybe the data table is using the property reference as the index? The data I'm getting should be unique so the for loop is not needed if I can find the syntax to just get a match, I'm still new to C# and its early on in the script so I will go through and look to improve as I go.